# Is it possible to show same instance of UIView on multiple views?

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to show same instance of UIView on multiple views?

I've got a UIView instance,

```
UIViewController* page01 = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Page01" bundle:nil];
```

And I need to display the contents of page01 on multiple views.

I tried below, but it failed. it seems that multiple view instances are needed to display on multiple views.

```
[self.view01 addSubview:self.page01.view];
[self.view02 addSubview:self.page01.view];
```

Are there any workarounds?
Please give me some hints.
Thanks.

Comment: no, an instance of `UIView` can have only one `superview` at the same time, if you need it the _same_ view multiple times, you have to create the proper amount of instances.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it is not possible. A view is linked into a view hierarchy with one superview only and has a rectangle in that view.
2. Typically you put the view into a separate nib and load the nib multiple times.